# Is there an algorithm for matchmaking?

Tags: algorithms, game-development

I am interested to know if there is an existing algorithm to start a multiplayer game, for example, poker. What steps do we need to take when the player enters the "matchmaking phase"?

I expect something like:

1. Player N enter the matchmaking room.
2. The player is saved in a database in "Waiting" status.
3. Every 10 seconds, the server starts a job and selects 5 players in the status "Waiting" and sends each of them the websocket link where they have to connect to play.
4. The players selected for the game are removed from the database.

I know this is not a good algorithm, it was also an example to let you know which level of detail I would like.

Is there a good algorithm to do this? Since it is a well known problem I expect something but I have not found much online.

Edit 1:
Some more details since it seems this problem is too general at the moment:

1. Assume we are developing a poker app
2. the app is planned to be used by millions of players
3. I expect a distributed system (since it has to scale for millions of users)
4. we can start the game if there are at least 4 players and a maximum of 8 (per match).
5. Regarding the choice of the players in the match I would like to keep this part simple. Let's say each player has a "score" that correspond to the number of match where he/she won.
6. No constraints on the technology used (queue, sql-db, no-sql db etc).

Comment: What makes you say it's not a 'good' algorithm?  It might be perfectly adequate depending on your requirements.  I would say at the very least you'd want to select as many groups of 5 that you can each time or you could easily fall behind if more than 5 people are joining every 10 seconds.

Comment: I know it could work (with some basic optimization like you suggest) but I was hoping for something "production ready" that has already been tested and that could scale well with many users. There are sites like chess.com for example that do this for millions of players (and there are many others). Which algorithm are they using? (maybe they keep it secret that's the reason why I have not found answers online at the moment)

Comment: The main problem here is that you completely skip the detailed requirements. What exactly do you expect from an algorithm here? The problem may sound like it should have been solved sufficiently often that there should be a standard solution, but in fact most implementations would have their own requirements and peculiarities which may or may not apply to you.

(continued)

Comment: For example, you might want to select groups based on affinity, comparable player strength, likeliness to conspire against other players, etc. These choices would influence the algorithm considerably. If you have none of these requirements, the most simple algorithm (such as your proposed one) that you can implement in an hour or two would likely suffice, and that's not something that requires consulting the combined wisdom of thousands of SE readers :-)

Comment: The GameDev stack is likely to have better answers for how matchmaking lobbies work.

Comment: Instead of every 10 seconds, I would try matchmaking immediately when a player enters the "waiting" state. Why wait 10 seconds when enough players are ready? Why run a job every 10 seconds when noone at all is willing to play?

Comment: The term "matchmaking" suggests that you want to select groups of players that satisfy some criteria of "good match". Like when a dating app tries to find someone compatible with you.

Comment: The Gale–Shapley algorithm?

Comment: @JackAidley there is a way to make them notice this question?

Comment: @AM13 I'll respond to [your comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/353809/am13) here if you don't mind. The 'queue' is just a place to hold the "waiting" users. An in memory queue would relive you of DB IO for this fairly transient state. You said it "selects 5 players". A queue makes it easy to chose the 5 who've waited the longest. First in, first out. When you say, "Every 10 seconds", that's when you make me think of polling. I don't know where you got the 10 from but if you want to rate limit to protect resources this does it if you stick to 5 and not everyone.

Comment: What could that really mean?

How could a game, for example, poker, have a 'matchmaking' phase?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin for matchmaking I mean the phase when the user clicks "start game" and has to wait while the server selects 4 other players to play with him.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Shame that wasn't made clear…

Comment: @candied_orange good clarification! The 10 seconds was just an example so it was not a requirement.

I have tried to write a draft of the algorithm but something is still missing (at least for me). It was too long so I wrote it as an answer to my own question. I would appreciate a comment if you have time. (I ask you too since you seem interested in the topic).

Comment: Is this really on-topic for this site?

Comment: As a poker player, this is the exact opposite of what I want.  I don't want to be matched with people of comparable "score".  I want the easiest opponents I can get to maximize the amount of money I get, and minimize the risk of collusion between opponents.  I want random assignment.  Which is why that's what all the big poker tourneys including WSOP and WPT use it.  You get assigned a random table and a random seat at that table, and when tables are broken up you draw new random seat assignments from the available pool.

Comment: Also the problem with your queue idea is that if me and my friend want to cheat by telling each other our cards, we can almost assure the chance of getting the same table by clicking join at the same time.  You need a randomization element.

Comment: the poker game was just an example of a general problem. However, the cheating part was interesting and it is something to be considered

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm hesitant to call this an algorithm but there are two basic approaches to this kind of thing: polling and events.

What you are describing is polling: on some sort of schedule, you check and see if there are enough players to start a game.

The other approach is event-based: when someone joins you check to see if there are enough players to start a game.

There was a time when I would have told you that events are always superior to polling.  I've come to learn however that both techniques have their place.  Polling has been overused but it has advantages.  The key advantage is that it's easy to implement and has some inherent fault-tolerance: if you have some sort of temporary issue (like a network issue) that's been resolved, polling will tend to resume without issue.  Events can be trickier in such scenarios.

In your case, the main advantage of polling might be that it might reduce the amount of spurious starts.  What I mean is that if you have someone who joins the room and then immediately leaves, you are much less likely to start a game that suddenly ends because one of the players has left.

You can solve for that in the event-based approach, but it tends to be a little trickier.  The big advantage with events is that under heavy load, you will tend to spread your game starts out.  If you use polling, you might end up usage spikes every 10 seconds and idle times between.

In a nutshell, I think both approaches are valid and you can combine the two to do things like generate an event every 10 seconds to make sure nothing has been dropped.

Comment: This could be a good starting point, even though I was hoping for something more specific

Comment: @AM13 The problem is that there are many potential solutions, but which one is appropriate for your situation is unknown.  I will give you the general answers for free. Figuring out which one is a good choice in a real-world situation is how I put food on the table.  That said, with more context, I can give more specific advice.

Comment: You can imagine building this for a poker app so that we can think of a specific example. We could ignore the "levels" of the players at this stage (no need to match very good players with good players and bad players with bad players).  
I would like something to scale well if possible.
If you need more info let me and thank you for your time.

Comment: The advantage of polling is you can let the event make a minor change of state and wait for the poll to deal with that state. This protects you from bursts that could overload. It's how hardware interrupts work.

Comment: @AM13: it sounds like your ideal algorithm is "when there's 5+ players in the queue, then move the first 5 to a game"

Comment: @candied_orange Polling can create bursts.  I've seen scenarios where a process sits idle for e.g.: 24 hours and has to process 24 hours of changes in a few minutes and starves out other processes.

Comment: @JimmyJames polling smooths out the processing at the cost of queing up unfinished work. That only starves out other processes if you set the polling more frequent than the system can handle. Set a max queue size and you've no risk of filling up memory, instead you risk dropping work.

Comment: @candied_orange "polling smooths out the processing at the cost of queuing up unfinished work."  Not really.  Polling often means you sit idle while the queue is filling and then you process all those events.  That's the opposite of smoothing the work out.  The load curve is like a sawtooth.  Queues can help smooth the load, but polling is not a reason for that.

Comment: @JimmyJames the polling acts to limit how much processing happens at once. If you only poll once a second no flood of events makes you process more often than once a second. The assumption here is adding to the queue is cheaper than doing the work. It's doing the work that is getting smoothed out. The queue is still dealing with bursts.

Comment: @candied_orange I've done troubleshooting on polling-based systems for decades.  Doing nothing and then doing all the work that has piled-up while idle is not a smooth load curve.  When the polling wakes up, it will burst the requests unless you have some limiter such as a queue in place.  You seem to be confusing queues and polling.  They are orthogonal.

Comment: @JimmyJames you seem to be using them differently. You can poll and then do one thing in the queue or do everything in the queue. If you do everything you get no rate limiting.

Comment: @candied_orange You can use a queue without using polling.  You can use polling without a queue.

Comment: @AM13 I tried to start an update for a proposed solution, but I still don't know enough to narrow it down.  For example, is this a distributed application?  Do you have a queueing infrastructure or are you considering one?

Comment: @JimmyJames I can agree with that.

Comment: @JimmyJames sorry for the lack of requirements. However, I expect that a system to scale well needs to be distributed (or at least planned in a way that we could make it distributed). Regarding the queueing, if it helps solve the problem we can include it.

Comment: @candied_orange how would you use a queue in this scenario?

Comment: @AM13 The simple answer is that you put the players in a queue and put in a rule to fire when there are 5 or more players.  Once you get to a point where one listener can't process the players fast enough, you have it send the lists of players to another set of handlers (perhaps through another queue) that are dedicated to creating games.  These are capabilities that are pretty ubiquitous on cloud platforms.

Comment: @JimmyJames I have tried to write a draft of the algorithm but something is still missing (at least for me). It was too long so I wrote it as an answer to my own question. I would appreciate a comment if you have time.

Answer (score 12):

A problem like this isn’t solved by thinking hard about it. What will happen that humans will run into something controlled by an algorithm, and humans can react in a way that has unintended outcomes. They can understand and manipulate the algorithm. They can walk away. They can unintentionally cause the algorithm to produce inappropriate behaviour.

What you do is make some effort to create what you think is useful behaviour. Then you invite real users and observe. You detect when the interaction between humans and algorithm produces a suboptimal outcome and change the algorithm, until you are happy.

Then you try it with a group of drunks, people who think of themselves as alpha males, and Japanese tourists, you observe, learn and improve.

Answer (score 0):

Following mostly JimmyJames and
candied_orange answers and comments (but also others) this could be an approach:

**Using a queue**

1. User clicks "start game", backend receives a request and add user in the queue
2. Backend check if there at least 5 players. Since not do nothing.
3. same for 2nd user up to the 5th user. At this point the backend send a message (websocket?) where the users can play.

- In AWS SQS (for example) there is an API to know the number of element in the queue

problems:

1. What happen if a user exit the matchmaking phase? How the Backend can know that?
2. In case of a distributed system, how 2 different istances of the same backend app avoid selecting a player for 2 differnt games on the same time?

**Using a DB**
Same as before but saving in a DB instead of a queue (mysql for example).

- each save on the DB will trigger the backend operations. The server Backend will check if there are at least 5 players waiting etc.
- using a DB we can perform a count
- we can use a select for update so that when an instance selct 5 players they will be marked as "IN_A_MATCH" (distributed system problem solved?)
- if the user exit the matchmaking phase it will send an event deleting the user from the table on DB.

Problems:

1. If each DB save will trigger the operation that means that for 5 players 5 thread (?) for checking if is possible start a match will be started. This does not sound right.

comments on this solution will be appreciated.

Comment: For the queue, that looks like a pretty good start for a happy path.  The challenges are going to be all the abnormal cases such as someone dropping out.  You can use the WS connectivity as a proxy (you should be able to get a notification on disconnect) but in my experience, WS connections are flaky and you need have client-side code ready to reconnect so immediately dropping them from the queue on disconnect might be a bad user experience.

Comment: "how 2 different instances of the same backend app avoid" one of the features of a queue (in general) that differentiates it from a topic (kafka topics aside) is that each message is read only by one consumer at a time. That is, if a consumer reads a message, other consumers will not see it when they get from the queue. If the consumer commits the read, it is removed completely. If the consumer rolls-back, the message becomes available for read again. This is one key advantage over using a DB: you will need to implement your isolation mechanism if you roll your own queue on a DB.

Comment: @JimmyJames You are perfectly right no problem in the case of distributed system using a queue. 
Regarding the user that abandons the matchmaking phase even if we have an event on the front end side that triggers the backend we cannot delete a specific message in queue (as far as I know at least).

If we suppose to use a DB for the "isolation mechanism" we could use the select_for_update functionality and in theory, it should work well. There are other reasons why you would avoid this approach?

Comment: You have a few obvious potential race conditions still. If server A finds 5 people waiting and server B finds 5 people waiting and server A puts them in a match and then server B goes to put them in a match... Or if a person drops connection while matchmaking is happening, depending on what order things happen in you either get a server that counted five people but now can't find five to match, or you get the dequeue trying to run after the person is already started in a match.

Comment: I don't think I'd actually use an off-the-shelf queue for this because I don't know of one that's necessarily a great fig for the problem, I think you'd spend way more time fighting with the queue, but the argument in favor of off-the-shelf software is that a whole team of specialists has spent way more time on it than you ever could and a whole lot of users have already found a bunch of bugs which have hopefully been fixed. (What happens if your server picks up a lock on the table and is then hit by lightning? Who knows!)

Comment: @user3067860 "You have a few obvious potential race conditions still. If server A finds 5 people waiting and server B finds 5 people waiting and server A puts them in a match and then server B goes to put them in a match..." Using a queue solves for this.

Comment: @AM13 "we could use the select_for_update functionality and in theory, it should work well. There are other reasons why you would avoid this approach?" That's one part of a potential solution, but there's more to it than that.  Aside from all the development effort required to get a table-based solution to meet your needs, I would say scalability, cost, and performance are reasons to uses a queueing solution.

Comment: @user3067860 Although there is an issue where if there are 5 players in the queue and you have 2 consumers, one might grab 3 and the other 2 and neither can start a match. That's why I would suggest a single consumer for the main queue and if you need to scale, you have that consumer delegate game creation.

Comment: @JimmyJames Using a queue doesn't solve that, because as you pointed out server A grabs 2 and B grabs 3 is _even worse_ than the failure mode of the db (A starts the match and B has to wait for the lock to lift, at which point B doesn't have enough players to create a match and you rollback B's transaction). With queues, unless you have some way to lock and read five at a time, you could fail starting a match forever as long as you have fewer than 5*n players (n = number of servers). And you have to requeue them every time you fail which means the waiting order gets out of order...

Comment: (The first issue was that there's no lock between reading the count of players and then reading the actual players. That's true in both cases. I actually hadn't considered that in reading off of the queue there's only a lock on the individual player, not the batch.) I'm kind of wondering if this is an interview question because it would actually be a great one. There's no obvious "right" answer, just lots of OK but difficult to get perfectly correct solutions that provide lots of discussion points.

Comment: @user3067860 I understood your comment to mean that you could have two listeners select the same 5 players.  I apologize if I assumed to much. That said, if you have a very active site, there's probably no issue with multiple consumers.  But the work of selecting 5 things off a queue and sending that list to some other thing is pretty light.  If your volume is too much for that, you have a really good problem as in: you're about to be rich.

Answer (score -1):

Requirements aren't here so it's tough to give a detailed answer, but event-based seems like the best way to go about this. You can even assign a gameId that increments after every game starts when you add a user to the database.

1. GameId=1
2. Player saved with Waiting and GameId
3. If enough players, start the game and increment GameId